# Deserializing List of objects yields empty list

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I have a RESTful WCF service that I am trying to send a list of tasks to. I found on other questions that you have to encapsulate the list and I've done that and the serialization looks like it is going through fine.

The XML that comes from serializing the list looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MobileRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <TaskRequests xmlns="MyNameSpace">
    <MobileTask>
      <TaskArgs xsi:type="GetUser">
        <Password>test</Password>
        <UserName>t</UserName>
      </TaskArgs>
      <TaskID>1</TaskID>
      <TaskType>GetUser</TaskType>
    </MobileTask>
    <MobileTask>
      <TaskArgs xsi:type="GetUser">
        <Password>test</Password>
        <UserName>t2</UserName>
      </TaskArgs>
      <TaskID>2</TaskID>
      <TaskType>GetUser</TaskType>
    </MobileTask>
  </TaskRequests>
</MobileRequest>
```

So the `MobileRequest` class has one property which is a list of `MobileTask` objects. The code for the `MobileRequest` class is pretty straight forward and looks like:

```vb
<Serializable(), DataContract(Name:="MobileRequest", [Namespace]:="MyNameSpace")> _
Public Class MobileRequest
    <XmlArray()> <DataMember(Name:="TaskRequests")> _
    Public TaskRequests As List(Of MobileTask) = New List(Of MobileTask)

    Public Sub New()
        Me.TaskRequests = New List(Of MobileTask)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The MobileTask class looks like:

```vb
<Serializable(), DataContract(Name:="MobileTask", [Namespace]:="MyNamespace"), _
 KnownType(GetType(Obj.GetUser)), XmlInclude(GetType(Obj.GetUser))> _
Public Class MobileTask
    Public Enum TypesOfTasks As Integer
        Unknown = 0
        GetUser = 1
    End Enum

    <DataMember(Name:="TaskID")> _
    Public TaskID As Integer
    <DataMember(Name:="TaskType")> _
    Public TaskType As TypesOfTasks
    <DataMember(Name:="TaskArgs")> _
    Public TaskArgs As Object
End Class
```

The type of TaskArgs changes depending on the TaskType. I've included an XMLInclude and KnownType tag for each possible type that TaskArgs could be. (this may be overkill but I did it when something with the serialization wasn't working and just haven't attempted to clean it up yet)

The code I am using in my tester app to attempt to Deserialize the XML is:

```vb
Using logg As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(logg)
        sw.Write(txtSource.Text)
        sw.Flush()
        If logg.Length > 0 Then
            Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(logg)
                logg.Position = 0
                Dim ser As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(SMS_VendorObj.MobileRequest)) 
                Dim results = ser.Deserialize(logg)
            End Using
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

This is from a simple winform setup that lets me paste in the XML so `txtSource` is just a textbox that I put the XML I get from the serialization into.

While running the test app I can step through the above deserialization code and after the `Dim results = ser.Deserialize(logg)` line `results` is the right type but the `MobileTask` list does not contain any items.

Am I missing something in the class files or is there something wrong with the way I am trying to deserialize the list?

If I've missed important code please let me know and I will update with whatever else is needed. I also edited out redundant pieces so I may have cut too much without realizing it.

**Edit:**
The `GetUser` class:

```vb
<Serializable(), DataContract([Namespace]:="MyNamespace")> _
Public Class GetUser

    <DataMember(Name:="UserName")> _
    Public UserName As String
    <DataMember(Name:="Password")> _
    Public Password As String
End Class
```

**Edit #2:**
After handling the Errors that the deserializer can possibly throw I found that the deserialization process is throwing an `UnknownNode` exception followed by an `UnknownElement` exception on Line 21, Position 3. The details say that the expected element is ":TaskRequests".

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed you already have XmlInclude. Could you show the definition of type Obj.GetUser?

Comment: @BartoszKP please refer to the edit.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `XmlInclude` attribute (the `KnownType` is irrelevant here as it refers to `DataContractSerializer`) to the property `TaskArgs`?

Comment: @BartoszKP Can you post an answer with your suggestion applied to the class I posted? I tried just simply dragging and dropping the tag to be after the `DataMember` tag and the environment didn't like that at all so I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've reimplemented your solution in C#, and what makes the difference is the fact that you didn't provide the namespace for `TaskRequests` in `MobileRequest` class.

To summarize:

1) You mix attributes for `DataContractSerializer` and `XmlSerializer` which makes this code hard to manage, I've used only `XmlSerializer` related attributes.

2) The XML you've provided **cannot** be the result of serializing the classes you've presented. It contains "MyNameSpace" on `TaskReqests` field, whereas in your code there are no namespaces for `XmlSerializer` (only for `DataContractSerializer` which is not relevant here).

3) The minimal fix of your code to make XML you've given deserialize <strike>correctly</strike> (see edit below) is:

```
[Serializable]
public class MobileRequest
{
    [XmlArray(Namespace="MyNameSpace")] //note the namespace
    public List<MobileTask> TaskRequests = new List<MobileTask>();

    public MobileRequest()
    {
        TaskRequests = new List<MobileTask>();
    }
}
```

(I've also removed `DataContractSerializer` attributes for clarity).
It's in C# but I hope you can easily spot the difference - giving `Namespace` parameter to `XmlArray` attribute.

Probably useful references:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14064/Using-the-XmlSerializer-Attributes

**EDIT:**

As it turns out, XmlSerializer can't deserialize what it serialized itself! Using the classes defined above with described fixes after the following code:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MobileRequest));

MobileRequest mr = new MobileRequest();
mr.TaskRequests.Add(new MobileTask() { TaskID = 1, TaskType = MobileTask.TypesOfTasks.GetUser, TaskArgs = new Obj.GetUser() { Password = "test", UserName = "t" } });
mr.TaskRequests.Add(new MobileTask() { TaskID = 2, TaskType = MobileTask.TypesOfTasks.GetUser, TaskArgs = new Obj.GetUser() { Password = "test", UserName = "t2" } });

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt"))
{
  s.Serialize(sw, mr);
}

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("test.txt");
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
XmlDeserializationEvents xde = new XmlDeserializationEvents();
xde.OnUnknownElement = new XmlElementEventHandler((o, e) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine("Unknown element:" + e.Element.Name);
});
xde.OnUnknownNode = new XmlNodeEventHandler((o, e) =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Unknown node:" + e.Name);
  });
var r = s.Deserialize(xmlReader, xde);
Console.ReadKey();
```

`XmlNodes` appear instead of TaskArgs! Removing all namespace definitions and references solves the problem. I've read about many issues with `XmlSerializer`, especially it's problems with namespaces, so if you can, you'll probably want to use `DataContractSerializer` or `NetDataContractSerializer` as suggested in this topic: [Why is XmlSerializer's Deserialize() spitting out a child object which is a XmlNode[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506196/why-is-xmlserializers-deserialize-spitting-out-a-child-object-which-is-a-xmln).

Comment: The environment keeps saying "Attribute 'XmlIncluedAttribute' cannot be applied to 'TaskArgs' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration". But while I was poking through the documentation you linked I noticed that you can handle the unkown element/node/attribute events to get more information as to why the deserialization failed. I'll try to get more information and update the question with what I find.

Comment: I read through the documentation a but more and switched the XMLInclude tags on the class to XMLElement tags on the property. I was also able to find some more information about the actual error and have updated the question.

Comment: Ok, that seems to have fixed that particular problem but now instead of the `TaskArgs` object being deserialized to whichever class I expect it is being deserialized as an array of `XMLNodes`. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: I've managed to get it working only without namespaces at all. I've edited the answer, and suggested other serializers - on this one, I give up :)

Comment: @BatoszKP: I give up as well. I've been fighting with it all week and haven't made much headway. What I have been able to do is change the `TaskArgs` property to a string and use that to hold the serialized version of the object I was trying to have the `serializer` handle. This requires me to add the `serialize`/`deserialize` step to the sending and receiving of each message but it makes it so the `TaskArgs` objects values are what I expect. Not exactly ideal but it works I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, not very nice, but well done on getting it working. In the end, it's all what it's about ;)